# Testing equality for ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two `ActiveRecord:Relation` objects:

```
actual
#=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<AdmTep id: 587730567, Student_Bnum: "145919559", Program_ProgCode: "750600237", BannerTerm_BannerTerm: 201511, Attempt: 1, GPA: 2.75, GPA_last30: 3.0, EarnedCredits: 30, PortfolioPass: nil, TEPAdmit: true, TEPAdmitDate: nil, Notes: nil, letter_file_name: "letter.docx", letter_content_type: nil, letter_file_size: nil, letter_updated_at: nil>]>
expected
#=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<AdmTep id: 587730567, Student_Bnum: "145919559", Program_ProgCode: "750600237", BannerTerm_BannerTerm: 201511, Attempt: 1, GPA: 2.75, GPA_last30: 3.0, EarnedCredits: 30, PortfolioPass: nil, TEPAdmit: true, TEPAdmitDate: nil, Notes: nil, letter_file_name: "letter.docx", letter_content_type: nil, letter_file_size: nil, letter_updated_at: nil>]>
```

Each contains a single record, and those records pass an `==` test,

```
actual.size #=> 1
expected.size #=> 1
actual.first == expected.first #=> true
```

but the `ActiveRecord::Relation` objects do not:

```
actual == expected #=> false
```

I am having trouble understanding why two `ActiveRecord::Relation` objects do not pass an `==` test. Can anyone help me understand why?

Comment: Can you show us how you gave `actual` and `expected` their values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is worth noting that an `ActiveRecord::Relation` just defines a database query. It only holds information about `where` conditions, `limit`, `joins` etc. clauses. But that query is not performed until a result is actually requested.

Therefore it makes sense that two relations that would end up returning the same result under a certain condition are not treated as equal. Because running both queries under another condition might return different results: Maybe because they return timestamps or the return is randomly ordered.

The query is performed once a result is needed: When you call `each` or `all` for example. Or in your example: `size` or `first`. Once the query ran the actual result is returned (and not a `Relation` object anymore). Therefore all later comparisons return `true`.

Comment: But the irb output shows the record from the database before he calls those functions on the relation, so the query must have been performed already.

Comment: Great thanks! So let's say I have a scope that returns an ActiveRecord::Relation.  What would be the best practice to test this scope, given that two active relations containing the same record might not evaluate to true.

Comment: @stoebelj: You could call `to_sql` on a Relation. That returns the `SQL` query that would be send to the database. If the Relation structure is the same then the `SQL` query should equal: `actual.to_sql == expected.to_sql `

Comment: After calling .to_sql I found that the sql to fetch the two Active Relations was indeed different.So instead, I did a full slice of each object (making an array of active records) and compared the two arrays, which worked. There might be something more elegant out there, but there it is.